# Macro Condition (if cell is empty select the cell in previous column)

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am making a macro for a certain task. That checks the date order of each columns in descending order. And I want a condition for column "AM"(<Range("AM"& i).Value Then) that if its empty then it must check the pre ious cell that has value(ex.column AK)

```
Dim lastRowAP As Long
lastRowAP =Cells(Rows.Count,"AP").End(xlUp).Row

For i=4 To lastRowAP
If Range("AP"& i).Value="" And Range("AO"& i).Value <Range("AM"& i).Value Then
Range"AO"&i).Interior.Color= RGB(255,0,0)
Range("CA"& i).Value = "G"
End if
Nexti
```

I haven't tried anything as I am new to this. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim lastRowAP As Long
    Dim sValue, i As Long, j As Long
    lastRowAP = Cells(Rows.Count, "AP").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To lastRowAP
        If Range("AP" & i).Value = "" Then
            sValue = Range("AM" & i).Value
            ' If cell AMi is blank, locate the non-blank cell on the left
            If sValue = "" Then
                For j = Cells(1, "AM").Column - 2 To 1 Step -2
                    sValue = Cells(i, j).Value
                    If sValue <> "" Then Exit For
                Next
            End If
            If sValue <> "" And Range("AO" & i).Value < sValue Then
                Range("AO" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Range("CA" & i).Value = "G"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your on answering me, but it is not working, also I forgot to mention that it needs to skip 1 previous column then check the second 1 from the left

Comment: Do you talk about the logic of `locate the non-blank cell`? I would suggest you share the detail of logic with sample date.

Comment: Yes, but I need to skip 1 column because it has different content like from AM i will skip AL and proceed to column AK and if the column AK is blank again I will skip column AJ and check AI instead, and so on

Comment: See the updated code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is currently working, however I copied the code and change the current columns to check the next columns with the same purpose. And I get the 'Complie error: Duplicate declaration in current scope' error

Comment: Update the post w/ the latest code. It's difficult to say anything w/o seeing the code.